# Posting JSON object with array through Symfony API

Tags: javascript, json, forms, symfony, post

I'm trying to post a JSON objet like the following to my backend app developed with Symfony (using API Plateform, front-end App with VueJS) :

```json
{
    "weight": "10",
    "category": ["/api/categories/2", "/api/categories/79"]
}
```

Here what I've tried for my HTML form (which is in a VueJS template):

```html
<form action="/api/data" method="post" axiosMethod="post">
   <input type="text" name="weight"> <!-- value=1 -->
   <input type="text" name="category[1]"> <!-- value="/api/categories/2" -->
   <input type="text" name="category[1]"> <!-- value="/api/categories/79" -->
</form>
```

Here is the JSON file this form actually sends, which is not the one I want :

```json
{
    "weight": "1",
    "category[1]": "/api/categories/79"
}
```

I've also tried this (which does not work either, same result as the previous one) :

```html
<form action="/api/data" method="post" axiosMethod="post">
   <input type="text" name="weight"> <!-- value=1 -->
   <input type="text" name="category[]"> <!-- value="/api/categories/2" -->
   <input type="text" name="category[]"> <!-- value="/api/categories/79" -->
</form>
```

Does anyone know I could put the two category values together in a single array ? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What about `name="category[1]"` and `name="category[2]"`?

Comment: if the second form was send right to php it would result in the json array you wanted. However, js transforms it into the wrong array, so I suppose it's neither a symfony nor a php question but might have a lot to do with js. You might try `name="category"` and hope that multiple values are transformed into an array in your js implementation...

Comment: @Jakumi I just checked with my team, and you're right, it has more to do with JS than anything else. I've found a way to overcome it, I only had a bit of JS programming to do. Thanks !